# How to construct Windows::UI::Xaml::Style class programmatically

Tags: winrt-xaml, c++-winrt

I'm trying to programmatically construct a `winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Style` object for all buttons. But, some of the style `Setter` doesn't work I expect.

In summary, `Setter`s for `BorderThickness`, `BorderBrush`, `Foreground` and `Margin` properties doesn't work. On the other hand, `Setter`s for `FontSize` and `Background` properties work right. How can I correct this matter.

a `Style` object is constructed like this code.

```cpp
void MainPage::SetStylePropertySetters()
{
    coloredButtonStyle.Setters().Append(Setter{ // doesn't work
        Control::BorderThicknessProperty(),
        box_value(ThicknessHelper::FromUniformLength(10.5)) });

    coloredButtonStyle.Setters().Append(Setter{ // doesn't work
        Control::BorderBrushProperty(),
        box_value(Colors::Black()) });

    coloredButtonStyle.Setters().Append(Setter{ // works right
        Control::FontSizeProperty(),
        box_value(50) });

    coloredButtonStyle.Setters().Append(Setter{ // doesn't work
        Control::ForegroundProperty(),
        box_value(Colors::White()) });

    coloredButtonStyle.Setters().Append(Setter{ // doesn't work
        FrameworkElement::MarginProperty(),
        box_value(ThicknessHelper::FromLengths(10, 10, 0, 0)) });

    coloredButtonStyle.Setters().Append(Setter{ // works right
        Control::BackgroundProperty(),
        GenerateGradient() });
}

LinearGradientBrush MainPage::GenerateGradient()
{
    GradientStopCollection gradientStopCollection{};

    GradientStop gs1;
    gs1.Color(Colors::Yellow());
    gs1.Offset(0);
    gradientStopCollection.Append(gs1);

    GradientStop gs2;
    gs2.Color(Colors::Orange());
    gs2.Offset(0.5);
    gradientStopCollection.Append(gs2);

    GradientStop gs3;
    gs3.Color(Colors::Red());
    gs3.Offset(1.0);
    gradientStopCollection.Append(gs3);

    return LinearGradientBrush(gradientStopCollection, 0.0);
}
```

Then the style is applied to a button in the constructor of the `MainPage`.

```cpp
MainPage::MainPage() :
    coloredButtonStyle{ xaml_typename<Button>() }
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Apply a style to a button named DefaultButton
    SetStylePropertySetters();
    DefaultButton().Style(coloredButtonStyle);
}
```

The main page has one button named `DefaultButton`.

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="HeadedAppDesign.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:HeadedAppDesign"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="DefaultButton" Content="Button"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

This produces the following result:

[image: Rendered output]

Comment: If you try to use SolidColorBrush to set the color to BorderBrush and Foreground(e.g. `box_value(SolidColorBrush{Colors::Blue()})`), will it work?

Comment: Yes, that works very good! Thanks a lot. After reading your comment, I checked BorderBrush and Foreground property at Microsoft docs. And I found these property's type is Brush not Color. So I need to pass Brush object like SolidColorBrush instead of Color object like Black or White.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `Thickness` type properties, pass string object as the same 
 format in XAML markup. And for `Brush` type properties, pass one of the derived class object of `Brush` class.

```
void MainPage::SetStylePropertySetters()
{
    coloredButtonStyle.Setters().Append(Setter{
        Control::BorderThicknessProperty(),
        box_value(L"10.5") });

    coloredButtonStyle.Setters().Append(Setter{
        Control::BorderBrushProperty(),
        SolidColorBrush(Colors::Black()) });

    coloredButtonStyle.Setters().Append(Setter{
        Control::FontSizeProperty(),
        box_value(50) });

    coloredButtonStyle.Setters().Append(Setter{
        Control::ForegroundProperty(),
        SolidColorBrush(Colors::White()) });

    coloredButtonStyle.Setters().Append(Setter{
        FrameworkElement::MarginProperty(),
        box_value(L"10, 10, 0, 0") });

    coloredButtonStyle.Setters().Append(Setter{
        Control::BackgroundProperty(),
        GenerateGradient() });
}
```

The margin, border width and color, font size and color and background gradient of the button all applied as I expected.

[image: result]